# How to hide window surface using EGL on weston wayland

Tags: opengl-es, freeglut, egl, wayland, weston

I  am rendering my GL content using EGL on Weston compositor.
the content displayed well.
my requirement is to hide and show the surface with some event.
Can you suggest how to do that?

when i was using glut with x11 , i used  glutShowWindow();  and  glutHideWindow();

is there way to simply hide the shell surface and then show it again on Weston?